# Show % of expectation met

Tags: tableau-api

My business has an expectation that action is taken on a case within 2 days of it being assigned. I am building a report in Tableau to show the average for each user, but I also need to show it as a percentage of their total. Example: Sally met the 2 day expectation 40% of the time.

I have very simple field:

```
[Employee Name]

[Unique Case ID]

[Case Assignment Date]

[Quality Action Date]

[Days to Quality Action] *(calculated field to show the days between case 
assignment date and quality action date

[Met 2 Day Expectation] *(calculated field that says "yes" if expectation 
was met and "no" if exectation wasn't met)*
```

How do I create that calculation or view in Tableau as a percentage? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect question to be answered with [LOD Calculations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm).

I will break the answer here into four calculations, however, they can easily be combined if you like.

The first will change your "Yes" and "No" string calculated field to 1 and 0 respectively. Thus changing to an integer and allowing for the SUM of times in which the goal was met to be found.

```
If [Days to Quality Action Date] <=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

That new calculation, we'll call it "Qualifier," leads to the next calculation which SUMs the number of 1s per person. (Take note the curly braces - they denote an LOD calculation is in use.) We'll call this calculation "Numerator":

```
{Fixed [Employee Name]: SUM([Qualifier])}
```

Next is the "Denominator" calculation which needs to count the total number of unique cases per employee:

```
{Fixed [Employee Name]: COUNT([Unique Case ID])}
```

From there the final calculation can look like this:

```
[Numerator] / [Denominator]
```

LODs are generally very powerful, but do take some getting used to. Hope this helps!

Comment: LOD calculations take place computationally prior to filters. One easy way around this is to place your filters “on context” (right click the filter and add to context.) The somewhat more difficult but correct method is to adjust the calculation itself. Give a few articles/blogs a read in this regard. The answer there is highly dependant on the structure of your data. I would sum up LODs by saying “with great power comes a great need for detail”